Identify a short animated movie about a walking tree in red shoes
I flew with Norwegian airlines and they played some cartoons on board. 
Among these there was this funny weird short animated story about a tree who took red shoes of a sleeping man and went on wandering. He always took something making the owner to follow him and this group was getting bigger and bigger.
The art style was kind of simplistic 2D animation, with caricaturous elements. The tree had two eyes aligned vertically rather than horizontally.
As of the origin of the movie, I'm not really sure. By the words in credits I assumed it to be French, but it might as well be Spanish/Catalan, which would make sense since there were some spanish flamenco(?) dancers in the story as well. But I could be wrong with both of the guesses, I don't speak French.
Does anyone know this? What is the name of the short?

The name of the short is "One, Two, Tree"
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6068004/




This answer would be better served if you included a bit of text explaining why this is the answer. Links can change or get removed.
